# Redirect to error page and show user friendly error

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling

In my application, I would like to redirect to an error page. There is a label that will show a user friendly error on the error page. I can redirect to the page. The matter is of setting the label to the user friendly error.

```
if (xy.Count() >= 1)
{            
    foreach (var x in xy)
    {
        employeeEmploy.Add(x);
        Debug.WriteLine(x.employee_personal_id);
    }
}
else 
{
    Security.ErrorControl.displayErrorMsg = "Employee Employ currently doesn't have any persons inside";

    Debug.WriteLine(Security.ErrorControl.displayErrorMsg); // class that set and get the error message i want to display

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("ssperror.aspx"); // I am getting to redirect .. just need to set the label to the error message.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the error message (or even better an id representing the message id) in the querystring while redirecting, so the last line would be:

```
  HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("ssperror.aspx?err_id=4");
```

then in the ssperror.aspx you can analyze the parameter err_id, retrieve and show the error message in the label:

```
if (Request.QueryString["err_id"] != null)
{
    lbl_error.text = retrieve_errormessage_from_code(Request.QueryString["err_id"]);
}
```